# Using Google Analytics without Javascript?

Tags: html, google-analytics

Is it possible to use the Google Analytics code on a website which does not support javascript or any server side scripting? (*For example a profile page on a website which allows to use only HTML*).

I have found out that analytics code can be used without using the javascript by calling the tracking image directly and send some data with it. I also found a couple of links but they use server side code also.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Technically, yes, since all you need to do is request __utm.gif from Google with a reasonable query string attached. This blog post on [Google Analytics without javascript or cookies](http://automateeverything.tumblr.com/post/20500736298/google-analytics-without-javascript-or-cookies) gives a good overview of what the __utm.gif request looks like.

Google Analytics actually has a pretty standard [php implementation](https://code.google.com/p/php-ga/), but I take it you want to do this without any dynamic language at all - just one static tracking pixel to register a count of pageviews?

There are a lot of reasons why GA is not going to work 100% (and may not work at all) without a dynamic language. Primarily, GA depends on javascript (or a server side language) to set a user's utm cookies, which keep track of info about the visitor's source, and which help associate pageviews from a single visit.

Since you may just want to track a count of hits to a single page, we may be able to do away with this, although I am not completely sure that GA will not just filter our hits automatically with some sort of junk filter.

But, all that said, if you want to try this, I'd place a 1x1 image on the page with the following source:

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=5.1.7&utms=1&utmn=1894752493&utmhn=www.lunametrics.com&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=1280×1024&utmsc=24-bit&utmul=en-us&utmje=1&utmfl=10.3%20r183&utmdt=Tracking%20QR%20Codes%20with%20Google%20Analytics&utmhid=1681965357&utmr=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Dtracking%2Bqr%2Bcodes%26ie%3Dutf-8%26oe%3Dutf-8%26aq%3Dt%26rls%3Dorg.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial%26client%3Dfirefox-a&utmp=%2Fblog%2F2011%2F08%2F18%2Ftracking-qr-codes-google-anaytics%2F&utmac=UA-296882-1&utmcc=__utma%3D230887938.1463229748.1317737798.1317737798.1317737798.1%3B%2B__utmz%3D230887938.1317737798.1.1.utmcsr%3Dgoogle%7Cutmccn%3D(organic)%7Cutmcmd%3Dorganic%7Cutmctr%3Dtracking%2520qr%2520codes%3B&utmu=DC~
```

You'll need to adapt the source a little bit to fit the site you are tracking - see this [LunaMetrics post](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2011/10/04/utmgif-request-parameters/) for reference. At the very least, you'll need to change utmhn (hostname), utmr (referrer), utmp (current URI), and utmac (your GA account number).

Comment: Does this still work?  The link to the blog post is now broken.

Comment: @Igal you should be able to view the blog post via [archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20130808235410/http://adambuchanan.me/post/20500736298/google-analytics-without-javascript-or-cookies). I can't vouch for whether or not this solution still works, I haven't worked much with GA in years.

Comment: Here's an updated link for the first link: https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsTrackingOverview

Answer (score 4):

Just point an image to the site with your account details, and you are good to go!

The format of the URL in the public service is:

```
http://nojsstats.appspot.com/your-google-analytics-user-account/your-website.com
```

For example:

```
http://nojsstats.appspot.com/UA-123456/your-website.com
```

Example (HTML code):

```
<img src="http://nojsstats.appspot.com/UA-123456/mywebsite.com" />
```

Example (BBCode):

```
[img]http://nojsstats.appspot.com/UA-123456/mywebsite.com[/img]
```

Example (CSS code):

```
body{
background: url("http://nojsstats.appspot.com/UA-123456/mywebsite.com");
}
```

---

### Note:

```
If your website uses SSL, you have to point to our SSL version:
httpS://nojsstats.appspot.com/UA-123456/yourwebsite.com
```

**Only use the SSL version if your website uses SSL.**
Credits: http://nojsstats.blogspot.in/

Comment: Nice find - I've never seen nojsstats before. You should include some credit to their site, though, since your answer is copied directly from http://nojsstats.blogspot.com/.

Comment: "**Only use the SSL version if your website uses SSL.**" Good note, better would be to use the following as your image tag: `<img src="//nojsstats.appspot.com/UA-123456/mywebsite.com" />` ... this will force that same protocol (http|https|etc) as the hosting site.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question while trying to figure out how to embed analytics tracking in a Google Slideshow. After following some references in the above answers, I realized that things have changed a little since the original answers were posted.

Google now has its Measurement Protocol which fills the same niche as `_utm.gif` did before.

- https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/
- https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference

The official guides and references are more complete than some of the previous answers.

simply put, send a get/post to

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/collect
```

With all the values you want to set (see the [massive reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference))

Based on that, as well as @greg Answer, the embedded HTML could be (untested):

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?utmwv=5.1.7&utms=1&utmn=1894752493&utmhn=www.lunametrics.com&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=1280×1024&utmsc=24-bit&utmul=en-us&utmje=1&utmfl=10.3%20r183&utmdt=Tracking%20QR%20Codes%20with%20Google%20Analytics&utmhid=1681965357&utmr=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Dtracking%2Bqr%2Bcodes%26ie%3Dutf-8%26oe%3Dutf-8%26aq%3Dt%26rls%3Dorg.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial%26client%3Dfirefox-a&utmp=%2Fblog%2F2011%2F08%2F18%2Ftracking-qr-codes-google-anaytics%2F&utmac=UA-296882-1&utmcc=__utma%3D230887938.1463229748.1317737798.1317737798.1317737798.1%3B%2B__utmz%3D230887938.1317737798.1.1.utmcsr%3Dgoogle%7Cutmccn%3D(organic)%7Cutmcmd%3Dorganic%7Cutmctr%3Dtracking%2520qr%2520codes%3B&utmu=DC~' />
```

Note: I do not like using `rel='stylesheet'` but find it "least offensive". (see the [HTML Spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#body-ok))