# Calculate installation count with Inno Setup

Tags: google-analytics, inno-setup

Does anyone know what's the best approach to calculate installation count of an installer using Inno Setup? Can it be integrated with GA?

I read somewhere that by opening a PHP page at the end of installation, we can calculate installation count, but it is still too vague for me to understand.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CurStepChanged` [event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents) to send HTTP request.

```pascal
[Code]

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  WinHttpReq: Variant;
  Url: string;
begin
  if CurStep = ssDone then
  begin
    try
      Url := 'http://....';
      Log('Sending GA request: ' + Url);

      WinHttpReq := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');
      WinHttpReq.Open('GET', Url, False);
      WinHttpReq.Send('');

      Log('GA request result: ' + IntToStr(WinHttpReq.Status) + ' ' + WinHttpReq.StatusText);
    except
      Log('Error sending GA request: ' + GetExceptionMessage);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

---

Not sure however what URL you need to use to link it to GA. There's another question that covers this part of the problem:
[Using Google Analytics without Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15265883/850848)

You can of course query your own web page (e.g. PHP) that does the calculation.

Answer (score 3):

For offline integration Google Analytics must be accessed via the new Measurement Protocol. Here is the same example from Martin but modified to access the Measurement Protocol:

```pascal
[Code]

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  WinHttpReq: Variant;
  Url: string;
begin
  if CurStep = ssDone then
  begin
    try
      Url := 'http://www.google-analytics.com/collect';
      Log('Sending GA request: ' + Url);

      WinHttpReq := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');
      WinHttpReq.Open('POST', Url, False);
      // see here the parameters : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#required
      WinHttpReq.Send('v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=pageview&dp=%2mywebpage'); 

      Log('GA request result: ' + IntToStr(WinHttpReq.Status) + ' ' + WinHttpReq.StatusText);
    except
      Log('Error sending GA request: ' + GetExceptionMessage);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Read about the [Measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide).