# How can I get website analytics data of bots and users with no javascript and/or cookies?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, web-traffic

Is it possible to get the info about website traffic without Google Analytics, for example?

Comment: What server stack? PHP? You can write your own server side visitor tracker

Comment: May you please tell me how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Google Analytics without Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265883/using-google-analytics-without-javascript)

Comment: @claudio, while it is a duplicate the answer from does not longer apply (by now one would use measurement protocol instead of manually creating requests for a gif). I'm not quite sure what is the custom on SO in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

For tracking without Javascript you can use the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/), i.e. you send a request to the Google Analytics Server with query parameter that specify the type of interaction (pageview, event etc) and  the data you want to track.

General info is found in the [protocol reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference), a [list of valid parameters is here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters), and if you want to test your tracking requests you can use the [hit builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/), which allows you to assemble, validate and send a hit to Google Analytics.

As for tracking without cookies that probably won't work very well. You need a persistent id to assemble hits into sessions, and sessions into visits. Such an ID is usually stored in a cookie (your "no javascript" requirement means that things like local storage are out of the question).  You can either decorate all your links with a client id and use that to persist the parameter from page to page, or you use some sort of server-side [browser fingerprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint).

All in all this might be somewhat less trivial than you assume, especially if you do not only want to track pageviews but also events that do not load a new page.