# disadvantages of pre-creating html serverside for phonegap app

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, cordova

I want to create a mobile application for an already existing website. This application will allow users to login into their accounts, upload files, view messages etc. This app will be created using Phonegap and as much js/css/html5 as possible. My question is: Most apps I have seen so far use JSON-Responses (or similar) and work with them right in the app. But what is the disadvantage of already creating the necessary html on the server and simply loading it into a div using jQuery? (is it even possible because of Same Origin Policy?) When you want to change some minor things of the application, it is easier in this way, but there must be a reason why I haven't seen this so far...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is it a bad practice to return generated HTML instead of JSON? Or is it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284381/why-is-it-a-bad-practice-to-return-generated-html-instead-of-json-or-is-it)

Comment: @Juhana not a duplicate, this one is about mobile applications. A lot of things there don't apply here (since the HTML is already on the device to begin with if data is passed).

Comment: I think you don't worry about it. Html creating in server or client have advantages and disadvantages. Pre-creating html have many advantages: easy change template, content  html then don't need update app (facebook + google was pre-creating html server side). Your server was ready, why you change? I have app apply same idea as you, and it very good.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML and templates are already cached locally - so by passing JSON data instead of HTML fragments you're *passing less data*, network traffic is usually a limiting factor in mobile apps.

From a design point of view only asking the server for data (and not presentation logic) also makes for better separation of concerns and architecture very often. It's also easier to cache data than presentation because of user preferences and such.

On the upside - sending data will make presenting it slightly faster since less work has to happen on the client side.

As for the Same Origin Policy, it does not apply for mobile apps so don't worry about it.

Comment: On the other side - I can save pretty much time when developing the app as the template engine is already existing on my server and a json api would have to be developed again... Caching is not really necessary as most of the data change pretty often. So as I can see there is only "traffic vs. easier development"?

Comment: @Pi_isnt_42 yes, if you already have the server in place what you're suggesting can be a viable strategy.