# Jquery AJAX return raw data or ready-to-use HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am building a mobile app with Jquery mobile. Some data I need to request from an API and display inside the app.

now I have two options:

1. My API returns Json and I need some Javascript to format it to
   display in my app (it'a a list , so I would loop through it and
   append to the list)
2. My API returns ready HTML which I just need to include in some
   container. For this case I found this method:  `$( "#result" ).load("ajax/test.html" );`

Which one is best practice and how would you realize itt

Comment: There are some pretty in depth answers here : [Why is it bad practice to return generated html instead of json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284381/why-is-it-a-bad-practice-to-return-generated-html-instead-of-json-or-is-it)

Comment: Why not use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org) templates?

Comment: Use first option. Scalable, maintanable

Answer (score 1):

I have certainly seen it done both ways.  Here are some "bright-line rule" suggestions that you might consider.

(1) If the content is going to be treated by the app as "a black box" ... *"don't look at, we're not going to have to interact with it, all we need to do here is to **display** it, whatever it is"* ... then it might be entirely appropriate to let the server do all the work for you. (Especially if there are many possibilities, *and* "the server would know best," *and* "the app really doesn't have to give-a-damm.")  You want to avoid creating unnecessary dependencies or duplication between the app and the server.

But ...

(2) If the content is something that the *app* is going to have to interact with, and/or is going to need to "style" or somesuch, then the logic within the *app* should probably be doing it.  You want to avoid creating unnecessary dependencies or duplication between the server and the app.  *(Notice how the words, "server" and "app," are reversed in this paragraph.)*

The concept is sometimes called "separation of concerns."  If whatever-it-is is "more the server's concern than the app's," *and* "the app can afford to be 'unconcerned,'" then the server can hand-over *au fait accompli.*  Otherwise, it probably should be handing you data.

In any case:  "it is an *engineering* judgment-call for you, the engineer, to make and defend."