# using javascript to loop through drop down html array

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop, dropdown

I'm trying to populate a drop down menu with a javascript array.  I can get individual elements to show up but not the entire array.  I'm sure this question has been asked before, but can't find any references.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
var sex=["male","female", "unknown"];

for (i=0;i<sex.length;i++){
var opt = document.createElement("option");
document.getElementById("m").innerHTML=sex[i];
}
```

The html is:

```
    <form name = "demo">
    <table id = "demo">
    <th>Demographics</th>
    <tr><td>Sex</td><td><select><option id="m"></option></select></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: The current code overwrites the list each iteration.

Comment: How would I fix that?

Comment: Have you tried using a for each cycle? Something like for( index in array). You could also try a for...of but is not compatible with IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below an non-elegant fix to your problem. You can refactor this to nicer looking code if you use the JQuery library, see for example [What is the best way to add options to a select from an array with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery)

```js
var sex = ["male", "female", "unknown"];

for (i = 0; i < sex.length; i++) {
  var opt = document.createElement("option");
  document.getElementById("m").innerHTML += '<option id="' + i + '">' + sex[i] + '</option>';
}
```

```html
<form name="demo">
  <table id="demo">
    <th>Demographics</th>
    <tr>
      <td>Sex</td>
      <td>
        <select id="m">

        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: This works perfectly.  It'll save me so much effort in writing redundant code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a method I typically use that works:

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/ojZdgz)

HTML:

```
<form name="demo">
  <table id="demo">
    <th>Demographics</th>
    <tr>
      <td>Sex</td>
      <td>
        <select id = "sex">

        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
//array to hold the persons sex
var sex = ["male", "female", "unknown"];

//array to store html to add to the select list
var html = [];

//loop through the array
for (var i = 0; i < sex.length; i++) {//begin for loop

  //add the option elements to the html array
  html.push("<option>" + sex[i] + "</option>")

}//end for loop

//add the option values to the select list with an id of sex
document.getElementById("sex").innerHTML = html.join("");
```

Comment: Try this again (didn't go through the first time)... this is perfect.  Thank you all for your suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

Use a template libary like underscore or handlebars or mustache. Its bad practice to generate html from javascript.

Comment: Can you elaborate why you believe it is bad practive to generate html from JavaScript.  Does underscore,handlebars, and mustache use JavaScript?

Comment: You can Google it, you will get lot's answers for it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284381/why-is-it-a-bad-practice-to-return-generated-html-instead-of-json-or-is-it