# How to correctly return html template from ajax request with Symfony

Tags: ajax, symfony, templates, twig

I was wondering how to return correctly an HTML template (SEO friendly) from an ajax call.

In my app, I use 2 differents ways to return response:

**For simple template:**

```
public function ajaxCallAction() {
//.....
    $response = array(
        "code"      => 202, 
        "success"   => true,
        "simpleData" => $simpleData
    );

    return new JsonResponse($response); 
}
```

And in the JS I do something like:

```
$("div#target").click(function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        success: function(response) {
            if(response.code === 202 && response.success) {
                $("div#box").append(response.simpleData);    
            }
        }
    });
});
```

---

**For complexe template (more than 20 lines and various var):**

```
public function ajaxCallAction() {
    //...
    $listOfObjects = $repo->findAll(); 
    $viewsDatas = [
        'listOfObjects' => $listOfObjects,
        //....other vars
    ];

    return $this->render('myAppBundle:template:complexTemplate.html.twig', $viewsDatas);

    //in complexTemplate.html.twig, I loop on listOfObjects for example...
}
```

And for this kind of call, the JS looks like:

```
$("div#target").click(function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        success: function(response) {
            $("div#box").append(response);    
        }
    });
});
```

All those methods are working, but with the second one, we dont have status code (does it matter?) and I know that returning directly formated html template can be heavy (according to for example this topic [Why is it a bad practice to return generated HTML instead of JSON? Or is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284381/why-is-it-a-bad-practice-to-return-generated-html-instead-of-json-or-is-it)).

How are you guys doing ajax calls? What are the best practices here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my apps, I typically use something like that:

```
$response = array( 
"code" => 200,
"response" => $this->render('yourTemplate.html.twig')->getContent() );
```

Hope this help!

**Edit**

To return your response, you should use `JsonResponse`as explained in docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#creating-a-json-response

Simply use that:

```
return new JsonResponse($response);
```

Comment: I've looked for the documentation but didnt understand what does the "getContent()"  
  http://api.symfony.com/4.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_getContent

Comment: When you use $this->render('template.html.twig'), symfony returns a Response object; since you only need the HTML generated on this Response, you can use getContent() to get the HTML string and pass it to your front.

Comment: I really have to dig more but thanks ! I'll try that !

Comment: In fact, you should use `JsonResponse` to return your content to the front view, since a Symfony Controller must return a Response object. It's quite easy to use, take a look into http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#creating-a-json-response

Answer (score 0):

Try with "renderView" ;)

```
return $this->json([
   'html' => $this->renderView('template.html.twig', []),
]);
```